# Using Parse Push notifications with Swift on an iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is a push question.

```
        push.setChannel(teamToPost)  //send the team name to send
        push.setMessage(message.text) 
        push.sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock...
```

This code sends a success back. plus when I check in the Push data on Parse.com website, the message shows up in the Push data section. The installation table of channels is correct. However, it says it sent 0 channels and no one gets the message. Now it worked about a week ago. But I was sending a message to all channels. I switched to sending only one channel and now no actual pushes. Please note too that when I send a push from the Parse website, it does the same thing. It appears on the push data table but in the channels column, it says 0.
thanks.

Comment: Make sure that the push certificate on Parse is the release certificate if you are distributing your app to other people. The debug certificate will only work with devices with the app built in debug mode (i.e. from XCode directly)

Comment: @shim is right. Check out https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications and make sure to pay close attention to Section 7 :) The certificate you need depends on the stage of development.